# Processando instruções SQL com JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou tentando utilizar o JDBC, mas tendo dificuldades com o uso apropriado da linguagem.
Gostaria de passar o código sql a baixo para o java, e preciso de ajuda com o SELECT.

Em relação as variaveis sql1, sql2, sql3 e o uso dos respectivos where...(para mim estão errados). 
Eu fiz desse jeito tendo a clara impressão de que esta errado, mas os coloquei ai para mostrar o que pretendia com o meu código.

```
select * 
from voo, voo_comissarios 
where voo.voo_id=voo_comissarios.voo_id and 
voo_comissarios.com_cpf=580069359 and 
voo.voo_data between '1000-1-1' and '2019-1-1';

static ResultSet vooComissario() {
        ResultSet res = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM voo",
               sql1 = sql+  "WHERE voo.voo_data > ?"
               sql2 = sql1+ "WHERE voo.voo_data < ?"
               sql3 = sql2+ "WHERE voo.voo_id=voo_comissarios.voo_id";
               sql4 = sql3+ "WHERE voo_comissarios.com_cpf= ?"

        Connect();
        try {
            PreparedStatement stm;
                stm = con.prepareStatement(sql4);
                stm.setInt(1, serial);
                res = stm.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível recuperar os dados", "Erro", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
        CloseConnection();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual a duvida?

Comment: Quanto ao uso do sql1, sql2, sql3 e o uso dos respectivos wheres...(para mim estão errados)
Eu fiz desse jeito tendo a clara impressão de que estava errado, mas queria passar a mensagem da intenção do meu código.

Comment: Qual banco de dados está usando? O que são essas variaveis sql1, 2 e 3? O que você quer comparar? Eu sinceramente não entendi nada do que essa query faz.

Comment: Seguinte, eu estou usando as varias sql, para tentar replicar a consulta que fiz em sql (acima do código em java), como não entendo de jdbc foi nesse código meio estranho que cheguei.
Estou tentando fazer as restrições do where linha a linha, com cada variavel sql recebendo a consulta anterior e restringindo.

Comment: Veja a resposta, com o que foi apresentado, é o que deu pra entender.

Comment: Você precisa mesmo de todos os dados das duas tabelas? Você tem uma classe voo ou vooComissario? Você quer que os parâmetros sejam opcionais ou poderão variar? Qual o banco de dados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não explicou direito o problema, mas pelo que deu pra entender, se for para adaptar a query dentro do método, creio que deve ficar assim:

```
static ResultSet vooComissario() {
        ResultSet res = null;
        String sql = "select * from voo, voo_comissarios " +
                      "where voo.voo_id = voo_comissarios.voo_id and " + 
                      "voo_comissarios.com_cpf = ? and " +
                      "voo.voo_data between ? and ?";

        Connect();
        try {
                PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);;

                //se for usar números em cpf, 
                //utilize o tipo LONG no lugar de INT
                stm.setLong(1 , variavelCpf);
                //passe as datas no formato java.sql.Date
                setm.setDate(2, dataInicial);
                setm.setDate(3, dataFinal);

                res = stm.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível recuperar os dados", "Erro", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
        CloseConnection();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcosPinheiroMoura você pode aceitar a resposta como aceita, clicando no `V` ao lado.

Comment: Nobre cavaleiro Jedi do mundo Java, ensine a nossos jovens padawans a usar o *try-with-resources* para fechar recursos como `con`, `stm` e `res` automaticamente. Ensine aos nossos jovens aprendizes que é mais seguro e menos acoplado retornar uma lista ao invés de um `ResultSet`. Que a força esteja com você!

Comment: @VictorStafusa boa! hehe Pra falar a verdade eu não tenho muita pratica no uso do `try-with-resources`, mas não sabia que ele fechava todos os recursos sem precisar de finally, vou da uma pesquisada a respeito, valeu pela dica.